# VS2017/Resharper2017 "cannot resolve tag" for custom angular2 components in cshtml pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, typescript2.0

I am creating my first Angular2 (4) app in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition with Resharper Ultimate 2017.2.

I have created a number of custom angular components with valid selectors such as "my-app", but whenever I reference these components like `<my-app></my-app>` 
in a **CSHTML** page i get `Cannot resolve tag 'my-app'` warning in Resharper.

I have enabled Angular 2.x support for HTML pages in Resharper under Options -> Code Editing -> HTML -> JavaScript and Frameworks and this fixed the problem in my HTML angular templates, but not for my CSHTML pages used by MVC.

Note that when I run the application everything works fine, so it is purely a matter of Resharper static analysis identifying it as a false positive warning.

Is there anyway to work around this and make Resharper understand these tags in CSHTML pages too?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, I am getting exactly the same issues right now wirt VS Enterprise 2017 / ReSharper 2017.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The squiggly lines are caused because re-sharper is not recognizing those tags. I too was experiencing the issue.

Install the AngularJs 1.9.0 extension from re-sharper ultimate extensions. That should resolve the issue.